# Password hash generation algorithm in Moodle 3.7

Tags: moodle

How to write a function that generates a password like in moodle, what file is algorithm in, what file is the salt in?

is it?

password_hash(
"123",
PASSWORD_BCRYPT,
array(
"salt" => "SALT"
)
);

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/moodlelib.php#L4678

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, []);
```